# Checking Array content equality in linear time in Scala

Tags: scala, fold

I want to check if 2 arrays (target and arr) of integers have the same content (both arrays are unordered). Example: `Array(1,1,3,4,1,5)` contents are equal to `Array(1,1,1,5,4,3)` contents. I'm aware of the sorting solution and I'm trying to work out the linear time solution. I'm starting by getting the profile of the target array by `target.groupBy(identity)` and then folding the destination array using that profile:

```
def canBeEqual(target: Array[Int], arr: Array[Int]): Boolean = {
        import scala.collection.mutable.Map
        var profile = target.groupBy(identity).view.mapValues(_.length).toMap
        var mutableProfile = Map(profile.toSeq: _*)
        arr.fold(mutableProfile)((p, x) => {p(x) = p(x) - 1; p}).isEmpty 
    }
```

The problems I faced:

1. The default Map is immutable, I rebuilt the profile map using the mutable map. How would that affect performance?
2. I'm getting this compilation error:

```
Line 5: error: value update is not a member of Any (in solution.scala)
arr.fold(mutableProfile)((p, x) => {p(x) = p(x) - 1; p}).isEmpty
                                            ^
```

I added the types `arr.fold(mutableProfile)((p:Map[Int,Int], x:Int) => {p(x) = p(x) - 1; p}).isEmpty` and it failed with this error:

```
Line 5: error: type mismatch; (in solution.scala)
found   : (scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int], Int) => scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int]
required: (Any, Any) => Any
```

I'm currently stuck at this point. Can't figure out the issue with the mismatching types.
Also any recommendations on how to approach this problem idiomatically (and efficiently) are appreciated.

- Disclaimer 1: I'm a Scala beginner. Started reading about Scala last week.
- Disclaimer 2: Above question is a leetcode problem #1460.

Comment: How about `target.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length).equals(arr.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length))` This would be linear

Comment: Reread the **constraints** on problem #1460. Notice the relationship between `arr.length` and `arr(x)`. This problem can be solved after 3 traversals (4 lines of code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not going by algorithm modifications, but to clear the compilation errors:

```
  def canBeEqual(target: Array[Int], arr: Array[Int]): Boolean = {
    if (target.length != arr.length) {
      false
    } else {
      var profile = target.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
      
      arr.forall(x =>
        profile.get(x) match {
          case Some(e) if e >= 1 =>
            profile += (x -> (e - 1))
            true
          case Some(_) => false
          case None => false
        })
    }
  }
```

Note that adding or removing from an immutable HashMap takes constant time. (ref: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)

`forall` preferred over `fold` as one can break in between when the condition does not match. (try putting a print statements in match to validate)

Or you can do:

```
target.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length) == arr.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. The profile comparison seems to do the trick. I had to add `.toMap` to make it work since `mapValues` result is "not computed"? This is the output of repl without `.toMap`:

`Array(1,2,2,3).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
> val res104: scala.collection.MapView[Int,Int] = MapView(<not computed>)`

I also noticed I missed a corner case where one list contains items that don't exist in the other list (Handled in your code).

By any chance, do you know why the original code wasn't compiling?

Comment: `.toMap` was failing compiling because of the mutable map that you imported. removing import removed compilation problem on that line. and no advantage in having  `.view`, you can remove that as well